# Template plugin for Jenkins

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, build-automation, build-server

Is there any plugin available in Jenkins which allows you to reuse shared configuration across the jobs.. e.g I can define a template for Continuous Integration and other template for Running Tests and create multiple jobs from these template for different branches.

I know template plugin is available in Enterprise Jenkins but is there something similar available for jenkins open source?

I am looking for something similar to 
[here](http://blog.cloudbees.com/2012/02/using-jenkins-templates-plugin-to.html)

Comment: good for a first question +1 up

Answer (score 6):

I have found [ez-templates](https://github.com/JoelJ/ez-templates) plugin to behave well for Jobs templating. It is very young project and you will have to build it by yourself (which is very simple, see below), but still it is much more powerful than [Template Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Template+Project+Plugin) as it supports any types of jobs.

How to build:

1. Install [Maven 3](http://maven.apache.org/)
2. Clone/download the [ez-templates](https://github.com/JoelJ/ez-templates) git repo
3. Run 'mvn install' from the [ez-templates](https://github.com/JoelJ/ez-templates) checkout folder
4. Once build is ready go to the 'target' folder and find the ez-templates.hpi which is self contained plugin binary.

Comment: Do you mind explaining why it's more powerful then the Template Project Plugin?

Comment: For posterity, [https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EZ+Templates+Plugin](ez-templates) was released to the normal plugin registry shortly after this post.

Comment: It does not support pipelines and Jenkins Blue Ocean.

Answer (score 2):

How about the [Template Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Template+Project+Plugin)?

Answer (score 1):

The [Job Generator Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+Generator+Plugin) was released after this question was asked, which may fulfil some people's needs.

Unfortunately the [Template Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Template+Project+Plugin) still has some [issues](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?mode=hide&reset=true&jqlQuery=project+%3D+JENKINS+AND+status+in+%28Open%2C+"In+Progress"%2C+Reopened%29+AND+component+%3D+%27template-project-plugin%27), particularly in that it [lacks support for job parameters](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-23204).

Answer (score 1):

We use the Jenkins job builder to automate creation and management of our jenkins jobs.  It was basically built to allowing share configurations across jobs so you can easily create the same jobs with multiple configurations.  Check it out: http://docs.openstack.org/infra/jenkins-job-builder

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Copy Project Link plugin. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+project+link+plugin 
What I have done is to create a disabled (dummy) pre-configured job and when I want to create another one with the same configuration I just copied by using this plugin.

Comment: what if you want later to tune the 'template'?